# Cannot access staticfiles using Pycharm Community Edition

Tags: python, css, django

UPDATE:
I have updated the followin
This is the html file for that specific webpage.

```
<!-- load the path to your static file-->
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'music/style.css'%}"/>

{% if all_albums %}
    <h3>Here are all my albums:</h3>
    <ul>
        {% for album in all_albums %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'music:detail' album.id %}">{{ album.album_title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <h3>You don't have any albums</h3>
{% endif %}
```

Here is the CSS file:

```
body{
    backgroud : white url("images/background.jpg");
}
```

I have also changed the settings file like this:

```
import os

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "music\static"),)
```

You can see my project tree as under for more clarification:

[image: Project Tree]

Now there is no error but the background image that I am trying to get is now shown on that webpage:

Please help me out! Is this because of COMMUNITY EDITION?

Comment: Missing both closing single quote and percent sign. Error messages and stack trace are text please post then as text, not as screenshots of text.

Comment: I corrected them both but still won't show the background image.

Comment: "still does not work" does not help helping you. Please update shown code with committed modifications and show new error log messages.

Comment: I am sorry i am new to coding and stackoverflow so i didnt know how it works. Let me update the question real quick.

Comment: Please 1) run `collectstatic` and show output log 2) grab css file url from rendered page, open it manually in a separate tab and show/describe the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to load the static content from the CSS file, you have to use full static URL like

```
body{
    backgroud : white url("/static/images/background.jpg");
}
```

Comment: I did the necessary corrections. It still won't show the background image.